# Outlook 2013 refuses to start due to unavailable Microsoft Exchange Server

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Cannot start Outlook 2013. It refuses to start due to unavailable Microsoft Exchange Server. While all data passed is correct (email at hotmail.com or live.com). Why is that? How to fix it?
Some pics:
[image]

[image]

UPDATE:
Cannot resolve it using hotfix

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try playing with Control Panel -> Mail (Microsoft Outlook 15) settings. You could try to update your profile or delete it and recreate a simple IMAP / POP mail account. After you get that working, you can try adding a ME account.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're not the only one.

Try this solution.

- [This hotfix](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30427) was reported as fixing the issue [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeitpropreview/thread/a640dea8-b0fd-4cde-b5ec-2c077171a067).

There is other advice offered in [that forum thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeitpropreview/thread/a640dea8-b0fd-4cde-b5ec-2c077171a067).

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
Description:
I was trying to set an email account on a laptop already part of a domain. The domain is a W2008R2 AD running Exchange 2010. The client is a W7 Pro with Outlook 2010.

The problem arose in both cases:
- set that email account using autodiscovery
or
- set that email manually as Outlook Anywhere (RPC over https).

I was having no problem at all with the others emails clients, already set on other computers.

Solution
I found out that on the server, the service

**Microsoft Exchange Address Book**

was **not running**.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps.

1. Press the Windows + R key on the keyboard.
2. Type regedit -> Click OK.
3. Navigate to the following location HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles.
4. Delete the registry entries under the Profile key.

Comment: What does this actually achieve?